# How create DeepLinking in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How create auto launching app windows phone 8.1 for url?
I now that is possible for WP 8 and WP 8.1 SilverLight, but how do it in WP 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx